# How to set Sale Price As Tier Price in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, tiered-pricing

I want to set sale price (Sale price is custom price) as a tier price.I am create one product attribute 'percent_off_sale' in admin and calculate sale price what I want is set **"Sale Price As A Tier Price"**.Get product attribute in below template file.

```
Magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\tier_prices.phtml
```

Get attribute value using below line

```
$percentOffSale =  $product->getPercentOffSale();
```

code is here

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox $block */

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice $tierPriceModel */
$tierPriceModel = $block->getPrice();
$tierPrices = $tierPriceModel->getTierPriceList();
$msrpShowOnGesture = $block->getPriceType('msrp_price')->isShowPriceOnGesture();
$product = $block->getSaleableItem();
$productId = $product->getId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$percentOffSale =  $product->getPercentOffSale();                
?>
<?php if (count($tierPrices)) : ?>
    <ul class="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($block->hasListClass() ? $block->getListClass() : 'prices-tier items') ?>">
     <table class="tier-price-table-shipping" width='100%' border=1>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <th style="padding: 5px; text-align: center; background-color: #3399cc; color: white;font-weight: bold; ">Quantity</th>
               <th style="padding: 5px; text-align: center; background-color: #3399cc; color: white;font-weight: bold; ">Price</th>
               <th style="padding: 5px; text-align: center; background-color: #3399cc; color: white;font-weight: bold; ">Save</th>
               <th style="padding: 5px; text-align: center; background-color: #3399cc; color: white;font-weight: bold; ">Sale Price</th>
           </tr>

    <?php foreach ($tierPrices as $index => $price) : ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php
                $productId = $product->getId();    

               // $sanjay = $price['price']->getValue()*100/$percentOffSale;

                $discount = ($price['price']->getValue() / 100) * $percentOffSale;

                $salePrice = $price['price']->getValue() - $discount;

                $isSaleable = $product->isSaleable();
                $popupId = 'msrp-popup-' . $productId . $block->getRandomString(20);
                if ($msrpShowOnGesture && $price['price']->getValue() < $product->getMsrp()):
                    $addToCartUrl = '';
                    if ($isSaleable) {
                        $addToCartUrl = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')
                            ->getAddUrl($product, ['qty' => $price['price_qty']]);
                    }
                    $tierPriceData = [
                        'addToCartUrl' => $addToCartUrl,
                        'name' => $product->getName(),
                        'realPrice' => $block->renderAmount(
                            $price['price'],
                            [
                                'price_id'          => $index,
                                'id_suffix'         => '-' . $index,
                                'include_container' => true
                            ]
                        ),
                        'msrpPrice' => $block->renderAmount(
                            $block->getPriceType('msrp_price')->getAmount(),
                            [
                                'price_id'          => $index,
                                'id_suffix'         => '-' . $index,
                                'include_container' => true
                            ]
                        ),
                    ];
                    if ($block->getCanDisplayQty($product)) {
                        $tierPriceData['qty'] = $price['price_qty'];
                    }
                ?>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Buy %1 for: ', $price['price_qty']) ?>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                   id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($popupId) ?>"
                   data-tier-price="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->jsonEncode($tierPriceData)) ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Click for price') ?></a>
                <?php else:
                    $priceAmountBlock = $block->renderAmount(
                        $price['price'],
                        [
                            'price_id'          => $index,
                            'id_suffix'         => '-' . $index,
                            'include_container' => true,
                            'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_OPTION
                        ]
                    );
                ?>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo ($block->getShowDetailedPrice() !== false)
                        ? __(
                           // 'Buy %1 for %2 each and <strong class="benefit">save<span class="percent tier-%3">&nbsp;%4</span>%</strong>',
                            '<tr>
                               <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">%1</td>
                               <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">%2</td>
                               <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">%4</span>%</strong></td>
                               <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">%5</td>

                           </tr>',
                            $price['price_qty'],
                            $priceAmountBlock,
                            $index,
                            $tierPriceModel->getSavePercent($price['price']),
                            $salePrice
                        )
                        : __('Buy %1 for %2 each', $price['price_qty'], $priceAmountBlock);

                ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
    </ul>
    <?php if ($msrpShowOnGesture):?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                ".product-info-main": {
                    "addToCart": {
                        "origin": "tier",
                        "addToCartButton": "#product_addtocart_form [type=submit]",
                        "inputQty": "#qty",
                        "attr": "[data-tier-price]",
                        "productForm": "#product_addtocart_form",
                        "productId": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $productId ?>",
                        "productIdInput": "input[type=hidden][name=product]",
                        "isSaleable": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $isSaleable ?>"
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

[image]